# graphical explanation of a struct within another struct but a pointer to it,

Tags: c, pointers, struct, graph

I am new to C and structures, and I have a code that I am trying to understand, would someone kindly explain to me graphically how this two structures co-relate with each other, is like struct node within the struct graph

```
struct Graph {
    // An array of pointers to Node to represent adjacency list
    struct Node* head[N];
};

// A data structure to store adjacency list nodes of the graph
struct Node {
    int dest;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Comment: If you include an actual instance of one structure inside another, then they would be nested, and you would only be able to do it in one direction.  But since you are using structure pointers, then there's no problem having one instance *point* to another and vice versa.  It could even point to an instance of itself (if you changed the pointer type), either another instance of itself or in fact itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Graph` has an array of (possibly null) pointers to `Node`.
Each `Node` has a (possibly null) pointer to another `Node`.

One graph could look like this, for instance:

```
       +-----+-----+-...-+-----+-----+
Graph: |     |     | ... |     |     |
       |  |  |  0  | ... |  0  |  |  |
       +--|--+-----+-...-+-----+--|--+
          |                       |
          |                       V
          |                     +---+   +---+   +---+
          |            Node:    |  ---->|  ---->| 0 |
          |                     +---+   +---+   +---+
          |                     
          V
        +---+   +---+
Node:   |  ---->| 0 |
        +---+   +---+
```

Comment: so the graph struct just has addresses to the nodes of the first element of the node, is this correct

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (The graph contains an array of linked lists. If you're unfamiliar with linked lists, you should probably study them for a bit before digging deeper.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following graph with 6 nodes, numbered 0 to 5:

```
0---1---2---5
|    \  |  /
|     \ | /
|      \|/
3-------4
```

This can be represented by 6 adjacency lists:

```
[0] = 1, 3
[1] = 0, 2, 4
[2] = 1, 4, 5
[3] = 0, 4
[4] = 1, 2, 3, 5
[5] = 2, 4
```

where the list following `[i] =` lists the vertices connected to node `[i]`.

Relating the above to your data structure:

- `N` is 6.
- `head` in `struct Graph` is the collection (array) of adjacency lists.
- `head[i]` in `struct Graph` points to the first element of the adjacency list for vertex `i` (corresponding to `[i] =` in one of the adjacency lists above). It could hold a *null pointer value* (`NULL`) for an empty list.
- A `struct Node` represents an element in one adjacency list.
- The `dest` member of `struct Node` holds a vertex number.
- The `next` member of `struct Node` points to the next element in an adjacency list (corresponding to a comma in one of the adjacency lists above. For the last element of the adjacency list, `next` holds a *null pointer value* (`NULL`) to mark the end of the list.